# How to handle event between components and gameobject in a practical and effective way?

Tags: lua, event-handling, game-engine, gameobject

I'm recently working on a 2d gameplay framework which all about how to manage game object and their messages between them.I've learned ECS(Entity Component System) which is a data-drived and property-centric way to manage game object.But I will not use it , cause there is no proper ECS framework to work with the game engine I am using and I've not had a plan to implement it recently.In another word , we will not talk about ECS and data-drived and property-centric ways or some other game engine having built-in support for that.

**NOT DISCUSS**

- ECS
- data-drived and property-centric way to handle event and manage object
- Unity or something like that

What I'm trying do is to handle event and manage game object by a traditional object-centric(OOP) way which consider the whole world is built up by game objects . But the new stuff is that I still want to use component in the gameplay framework. The component here will not act like it works in ECS which is just pure data and no game logic at all . The components here have linkages to particular low level engine sub system or commonly used game logic for every game object which has it. For example , I have a Audio component code(**Lua**) like this :

```
local Audio = class("Audio",Component)

function Audio:ctor( params )
    -- body
    if params == nil then
        params = {}
    end
    self.type = ComponentType["Audio"]
    self.super.ctor(self.params)
end

function Audio:play( soundId )
    -- call audio sub system engine method to play sound
end

return Audio
```

And I also have a Health component like this:

```
local Health = class("Health",Component)

function Health:ctor( params )
    -- body
    if params == nil then
        params = {}
    end
    self.type = ComponentType["Health"]
    self.health = 100
    self.super.ctor(self.params)
end

function Health:addHealth( num )
    self.health = self.health + num
end

return Health
```

And the whole design can be illustrated by this graph:

```
GameObject 1 <------ *Component
                           | Render
                           | Position
                           | Health
                           | Audio
                           | ... ...
```

Each game object in the game inherits directly from the super game object and no descendants derived from itself . So the inheritance hierarchy of the game object should be just two level. We can do this because game object is composed by components which encapsulate the ability to handle game logic such as "playing sound" rather than inheriting from base game object to get the ability.But I plan to make the component have the OOP traditional inheritance hierarchy to deal with the complex situation in gameplay.It should be like this:

```
  Render
    /
   /  
Customed Render(which has customed shader)
```

The super game object is responsible for common operation such as "get component" and the code like this:

```
local GameObject = class("GameObject")

function GameObject:ctor( params )
    -- contain all the components the game object has
    self.components = {}
end

function GameObject:update( dt )
    -- body
    for i,component in ipairs(self.components) do
        component:update(dt)
    end
end

function GameObject:addComponent( component )
    -- body
    table.insert(self.components,component)
end

function GameObject:getComponent( type )
    -- body
    for i,component in ipairs(self.components) do
        if type == component.type then
            return component
        end
    end
end

function GameObject:handleEvent( event )
    -- body
    assert(false,"derived classes from GameObject must implement handleEvent method")
end

return GameObject
```

The A game object which is a derived class from super game object is really responsible for creating needed components and event handling. It like this:

```
local A = class("A",GameObject)

function A:ctor( params )
    -- body
    self.super.ctor(self,params)
    self.initComponents()
end

function A:initComponents( ... )
    -- body
    local render = Render:create()
    local health = Health:create()
    self:addComponent(render)
    self:addComponent(health)
end

function A:handleEvent( event )
    -- body
    if event.type == "addHealth" then
       self:getComponent("Health"):addHealth(event.data.num)
    end
    if event.type == "takeDamage" then
       self:getComponent("Health"):takeDamage(event.data.num)
    end
end

return A
```

The GameObjectManager is mainly responsible for maintaining the lifecycle of all game object and game object query such as "I want to get all the game objects within the explosion radius". It will look like this:

```
local GameObjectManager = class("GameObjectManager")
local instance = nil

function GameObjectManager:getInstance( ... )
    -- body
    if instance == nil then
        instance = GameObjectManager:create()
    end

    return instance
end

-- pseudocode just for simplicity here. Just imagine that it can handle 
-- all kinds of query and return the proper game objects
function GameObjectManager:query( ... )
    ... ...
end

return GameObjectManager
```

**So Far , I can use this gameplay design under this scenario of a tower defence game :**

game object A goes along with the path the designer designed and at the same time keeps attacking the target within A's attack range. To implement this game logic with following steps:

1. A uses AI component to find the path way points and uses the Move component to change position.
2. A uses GameObjectManager to query what targets can be attacked while moving.
3. After getting targets, A will iterate the targets and call their handleEvent(event) method on each target game object which derived from super game object as well to notify "takeDamage" event.
4. Target will handle the event in a proper way by its Health component.

**Summary:**

I use GameObjectManager to make game object communicate with one another instead of using pub/sub or sig/slot model. Because I think it is not going to need to subscribe the particular events a game object is interested in. You just has a switch in your handleEvent( event ) method to handle your event and it is more clean than the pub/sub. Another reason is that you always don't need to broadcast a event , cause you always can get the "targets" that are just and all you want to get , which is more effective. I also consider the game object itself as a "hub" to get a component from another one of itself. In one word , object to object communication via GameObjectManager and component to component communication via game object itself. And one game object is not permitted to communicate with component of another game object directly.

**The Questions I Want To Ask:**

1. is this kind of design I do is proper or right?
2. are there some obvious drawbacks in this kind of design or in some scenario which can not be deal with?
3. Some tutorials told me that I should put the handleEvent part in components rather than putting it in the game object. And the game object should just concern about receiving event from other game object and broadcasting it to all components it has rather than handling it by itself.But what I don't understand is that if I put handleEvent part in a component , how can I make sure this particular event handler is proper for every game object which has this component. For example , A and B both have a Health component which is used to detect if the game object is dead. If A is dead , the game logic is to remove A from scene , nothing else. But if B is dead , beside removing it , I also want to play a sound or a animation. In other words, the game logic of death for A and B can be totally different. In my design , there is no such problem , cause I handle the event in game object with components it has. And game object is naturally distinguishable.
   The question is if I'm missing something to understand the tutorial told me?